# apollo-express-server verbose output (mysql db)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, apollo

I am writing an application which uses apollo-express-server and GraphQL to query a MySQL server. Mostly it works, but I want to remove this very verbose output:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `name`, `description`, `image` FROM `units_topics` AS `units_topics` WHERE `units_topics`.`id` = 21;
```

So every query produces something like that, and for big queries it goes on for quite sometime.

My server set up is this, and uses Serialize for the database structure...

server.js

```
const app = require("./app");
const apollo = require("apollo-server-express");

async function startApolloServer(typeDefs, resolvers) {
    const apolloServer = new apollo.ApolloServer({
        modules: [
            require('./GraphQL/users'),
            require('./GraphQL/units_topics'),
            require('./GraphQL/a_flashcards'),
            require('./GraphQL/a_flashcards_performed')
        ]
    })

    await apolloServer.start();
    apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });

    await new Promise(resolve => app.listen({ port: 5000 }, resolve));
    console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:5000`);
}

startApolloServer();
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cors());

module.exports = app;
```

database.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var db = {};

const sequelize = new Sequelize.Sequelize(
    'xxx',
    'xxx',
    'xxx',
    {
        host: 'xxx',
        port: 'xxx',
        dialect: 'mysql',
        define: {
            freezeTableName: true,
        },
        pool: {
            max: 1,
            min: 0,
            acquire: 30000,
            idle: 10000,
        },
        // <http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators>
        operatorsAliases: false,
    },
)

let models = [
    require("./models/a_flashcards"),
    require("./models/a_flashcards_performed"),
    require("./models/a_flashcards_points"),
    require("./models/units_topics"),
    require("./models/users")
];

models.forEach(model => {
    const seqModel = model(sequelize, Sequelize.Sequelize);
    db[seqModel.name] = seqModel;
})

Object.keys(db).forEach(key => {
    if('associate' in db[key]) {
        db[key].associate(db);
    }
})

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize.Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Can anybody advise on how I get rid of this verbose output?

Comment: Firstly, you need to determine if the problem is in the application code or it is on the database side. We can't do this as we have no clue what your code is supposed to be doing and we do not know what your database structure looks like and if the query at the top of the question runs efficiently.

Comment: Its totally nothing to do with the database. The problem is the application side. The code is meant to be querying a database using GraphQL syntax and returning data. It does this, I just want to get rid of the verbose code in the console. The question is, "how do i get rid of the verbose output".

Comment: Then next time please do not tag your question with irrelevant tags as it can be misleading!

Comment: For slow query resolution, from your MySQL server, please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE units_topics; B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "units_topics"; and C) EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE (rest of your query); for analysis, please.

Comment: Suggest you delete this question. Logging has nothing to do with your performance problem. [How to disable logging in sequelize](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/sequelize-disable-sql-query-logging)

Comment: Modified the original question so as to stop distracting people from what I was asking for - that was exactly what I needed, thanks. Im new to all of this so wasnt sure where the output was coming from :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sequelize problem, thus in the constructor for the sequelize db call, add the new line for logging:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize.Sequelize(
    'xxx',
    'xxx',
    'xxx',
    {
        logging: false,
        host: 'xxx',
        port: 'xxx',
        dialect: 'mysql',
        ...
    },
)
```

Thanks to Michael Floyd who posted in the comments: [How to disable logging in sequelize](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/sequelize-disable-sql-query-logging)

Comment: Also I posted this question to ChatGPT and it got it right away :D